# Take an array<double>^ and return an array<Complex>^ pointing to the same memory

Tags: arrays, casting, c++-cli

I have a C++ function that takes an array (double*) as a parameter, does stuff to the data and returns a pointer of type complex* that points to the same data. I need to wrap this function using c++/cli, but I am not sure how to make sure .NET ends up with proper references to the memory. For instance if the user calls the function like this `Complex[] data = Process(new double[1024]);` I want to make sure the data doesn't get garbage collected when the function returns (and my `pin_ptr` goes out of scope) and also that it DOES get garbage collected when `data` goes out of scope.
How can I end up with two valid references to the memory, each of a different type?
Note: The underlying C++ function works fine, this is specifically a .NET C++/CLI question about how to get two garbage collected references to the same memory, of two different types.

```
#pragma unmanaged
complex<double>* NativeFft(double* real_time_data, int data_size) {
    // do in-place FFT on data (no allocations)
    return reinterpret_cast<complex<double*>>(real_time_data);
}

#pragma managed
array<Complex>^ Transform::Fft(array<double>^ real_time_data) {
    if (real_time_data== nullptr) {
        throw gcnew ArgumentNullException("'real_time_data' must not be null");
    }
    int data_size = real_time_data->Length;
    pin_ptr<double> data_ptr = &real_time_data[0];
    complex<double>* complex_freq_data = NativeFft(data_ptr, data_size);
    // now how do I make another reference to the data?
    // (I also need the Length field to be halved).
    array<Complex>^ managed_complex_freq_data = ???
    return managed_complex_freq_data;
}
```

Edit:
Here is some more information, since everyone says the obvious solution is to just copy the data.
What I am doing is a very large real-to-complex in-place FFT. The data comes in as an array of doubles, and essentially stays that way (obviously the values change), but after the FFT is done the correct interpretation of the data is that every pair of doubles makes up the real and imaginary parts of a single complex sample. The size of FFT that I would like to do is too large for a 32-bit system, but I wan't to get as close to that as possible so I don't want to sacrifice the memory needed to do a copy of the data. I could just always work with the data as doubles, but it would be nice to be able to treat it as complex since that is what it really is after the FFT.

Comment: It's a managed type (`^`), so you *don't do that*. Please read [What is the XY problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) and change your question accordingly.

Comment: The `new double[1024]` should get garbage collected after the return of the function, since it is no longer needed. The return value should be built from the `data_out` (you are done with `data` after the call to `NativeProcess`, so not sure why you think you need to use the same "memory").

Comment: I need to use the same memory because the array will be absolutely as large as it can be, I won't have room to copy it over to another array even if the original is then destroyed because for a brief moment both arrays will exist and I will run out of memory.

Answer (score 1):

I might be completely misunderstanding your question or your requirements, but wouldn't it be simpler just to copy the contents of the native array into a managed array, and let the GC do its work?

```
#include <complex>

using namespace System;
using namespace System::Numerics;

std::complex<double>* NativeProcess(double* data, int& size);

public ref class Processor
{
public:
    array<Complex>^ Processor::Process(array<double>^ data)
    {
        if (data == nullptr)
            throw gcnew ArgumentNullException("data");

        int length = data->Length;
        pin_ptr<double> dataPtr = &data[0];
        std::complex<double>* dataOut = NativeProcess(dataPtr, length);

        array<Complex>^ complexArray = gcnew array<Complex>(length);
        for (int idx = 0; idx < length; ++idx)
            complexArray[idx] = Complex(dataOut[idx].real(), dataOut[idx].imag());

        delete[] dataOut;
        return complexArray;
    }
};
```

Comment: For the 64-bit version of the software copying would work. For the 32-bit version not so much. Basically it is completely memory bound so doing the copy cuts the size of the array I can use in half.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about conversion from double to Complex. Is it possible to convert double, which is fundamental type, to Complex, which is managed type, without creating new object? If you need more details I can look for it.

But any how: you data will not be collected until any pointer is pointing on it.

Comment: In theory it is possible, in practice I don't know. In my C++/CLI code I take an array<Complex>^, pin it, then cast the pinned value it to a native complex<double>*. So the managed to native (and vice versa) isn't a problem. In C# it is easy to make a new reference to an existing array (just assign it.) But what I don't know how to do is combine the two operations, making a new reference but of a different type while in C++/CLI. Regarding your second point, that is true of valid gc pointers, it is not true of native pointers. If I can make a valid gc pointer that points to the data, I agree.

Comment: As I understand from the question, you need to "not lose" pointer more, what converting data. What's why I said "not sure". About second point in code we see array<Complex>**^**  and array<double>**^**, so gc should work.